# integrating google account login in phonegap project throws could't connect to localhost

Tags: cordova, authentication, account

I am trying to integrate `Google Account` login in my `Phonegap` project. As per the tutorials I referred I had set redirect uri as

```
http://{localhost}
```

But when I tried this in my phone it throws error as:

```
Application Error
Couldn't connect to the server http://{localhost}/?code=4/...etc.
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: By simply googling I found this: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/google-api-oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser.html   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656820/phonegap-google-authentication

Comment: Ya..I had already tried these two links..but not succeeded.. I think its the pblm with redirect uri..please help me..

Comment: I havn't tried this yet. Perhaps i found somemore links. Please go on with this: http://www.excellentwebworld.com/add-google-login-into-phonegap-application/ ,  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/R-YpSbVw-kQ , https://auth0.com/login/phonegap/google-apps

Comment: I'm still stuck...anyway Thanks Rajmathan.